# Update ALB with changes in EC2 ip address

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

I want to have my EC2 instances use same IP even after start/stop. I cannot assign an Elastic IP because I have reached my limit (Not looking for "Request for Elastic IP increase" solution).

Is there any work around to make EC2 use the same IP address after start/stop?
(OR)
Is there any work around to make EC2 update their new IP address to all the load balancers (ALB & NLB) dynamically?

Comment: If you are using an ALB, your EC2 instance's IP address shouldn't matter at all. How have you configured things such that this matters?

Comment: Does this Server Fault question have the answer you need? https://serverfault.com/questions/662217/ec2-instance-static-private-ip-address

Answer (score 2):

**You will need to request a limit increase through the link on the bottom of the contact us page:**
https://aws.amazon.com/contact-us/

**EIP is different for VPC and nonVPC**

**VPC Limit increase page:**
https://aws.amazon.com/contact-us/vpc-request/

**nonVPC EIP limit increase:**
https://aws.amazon.com/contact-us/eip_limit_request/

Comment: I said, I am not looking for Elastic IP limit increase. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: You need to request AWS support as shared above link.  https://aws.amazon.com/contact-us/